# How do I disable network connection at prelogin?

Tags: login, 12.10, network-manager, lightdm

--- **This question is related to Ubuntu 12.10, since previous versions did not connect to network before login** ---

I had a bad boot today: the Ubuntu screen was blocked at startup time, after a green [OK] and a white blinking underscore. In recovery mode I figured out the problem: NetworkManager hung trying to connect to a wireless network that wasn't available anymore, and so I couldn't reach the prelogin level.

Anyway: I really don't like that the pc connects to a network *before* the user logging in. How is it possible to disable it?

Comment: Actually, I'm using the latest update of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and it does try to connect to the network before logging in.

Comment: maybe with updates it gets the behaviour of >= 12.10; I had 12.04 and it definitely didn't connect before login

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways that I know of, both involve the GUI for the network manager.

1. click on the applet and click on **Enable Networking** this will shut down all communication with the Network devices until you click it again and then you can shut down your computer and it will not connect until you select it again.

   [image]
2. In the **Network Mannger**, click on **Edit Connections** and you connection window will pop up

   [image]

   either double click on your connection or single click and then select **Edit**, you can then uncheck the box that says **connect automatically** and then click **Save**. It will then not try to connect until you click the **connect** option in the Network Manager(in my screen shot it currently says **Disconnect**) When you log off the the internet will be disconnected and will not connect when you log back in until you tell it to do so.

   [image]

Comment: THank you for the answer; is there a way to restore the < 12.10 behaviour, that is the PC auto-connects after the user login, and not before?

Comment: in the question was specified 12.10, but @jorge-castro edited it removing it... and now I have an answer to a question I didn't intend to do :-/